# Ajax Post getting cancelled in onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen duplicates of this question, however no solution seems to work for me. I'm trying to trigger an AJAX request based off of a link (the following). I'm writing in MVC 4. The AJAX request seems to go through well, I have a breakpoint getting hit on the other side, however the request gets cancelled by the browser. I can see this cancellation in Firebug, Chrome, etc. I found some suggestions that I need to return false at the end of the onclick handler to prevent other code from cancelling my event, however it doesn't seem to work. Are there additional quirks in the onclick handler that kill any outstanding AJAX requests? How would I stop that behavior?

```
<a href="" onclick="javascript:navClick('foo');">Employees</a>


function navClick(target) {
    var serviceURL = '/Consequence/'+target;

    try {
        var dealerID = "5";   
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Consequence/test',
            data: { dealerID: dealerID },
            type: 'POST',   
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        alert("exception");
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the cancellation in firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a class to the link and trigger the click event off of that

```
<a href="" class="linkEmployees">Employees</a>
```

then in your script

```
$('.linkEmployees').on('click', function(){
    //your ajax call here
});
```

Comment: Your solution works when I get rid of the link. I made it a button and it works fine.

Comment: I am not sure but if you want the link, try putting "#" instead of "".  I think you need to have something in there or it has issues.  would you mind marking my answer as correct?